# General question about Use Case diagram - UML

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

[image]

is the relation between the actor and *`UseCase`* allowed to be there? since *`UseCase2`* includes *`UseCase`*

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's allowed. `Actor` can perform `UseCase`stand-alone. *And* he can perform `UseCase2` including `UseCase`.